# Установка библиотек python без pip

Tags: python, ssl, pip

Проблема заключается в том, что сеть в которой я работаю почему то блокирует установку библиотек python через pip install (выдает ошибку связанную с SSL сертификатами) см. скрин. Проблему уже несколько месяцев никто не может решить. Возможно есть способ установить библиотеку python скачав файлы библиотеки с pypi.org, подскажите пожалуйста как это можно сделать?[image: Ошибка SSL]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте `pip install --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org %package%`

Comment: Из-за чего вообще возникает ошибка SSL - возможно давно систему не обновляли, какие-то корневые сертификаты SSL могли истечь. Теоретически способ из комментария выше должен помочь.

Answer (score 1):

Скачать `.whl` файл и установить его `pip install path/to/file.whl`

Или скачать `tar.gz`, распаковать и установить через `python setup.py install` из нужной папки.

Comment: Добавил 2 скрина в описание. Попробовал установить 'pip install path/to/file.whl' таким способом, не понимаю пакет установился или нет. Jupyter не видит его по крайней мере

Comment: Он зависим от других библиотек. Их также надо поставить.

Comment: От каких библиотек? Numpy?

Comment: lifetimes нужно писать с маленькой буквы

Comment: Все ровно не видет: "No module named 'lifetimes' "

Comment: похоже, что требуется модуль scipy

Comment: SciPy установлен, юпитер видит его

Comment: возможно нужна более новая версия

Comment: Версия SciPy - 1.5.0. Это вроде самая последняя

Comment: Больше нет версий. Судя по логу, пытается загрузить scipy, но не получается.

Comment: @DenisOsadchiy самая новая версия SciPy на данный момент - 1.8.0: https://pypi.org/project/scipy/#history

Answer (score 1):

Можно с другого компьютера (с той же операционной системой, битностью, и той же версией Python) загрузить нужный пакет и все его зависимости как whl файлы (`Lifetimes` - имя основного пакета, который нам нужно установить):

```
pip install wheel
pip wheel -w wheels/ Lifetimes
```

Появится папка wheels с примерно таким набором файлов (тестировал на Windows 7 x64, Python 3.8.6 x64):

[image: wheels]

Нужно эту папку перенести на комп, где возникают ошибки SSL, там установить все с помощью следующей команды:

```
pip install --no-index -f wheels/ Lifetimes
```

Ответ на основе информации отсюда: [Python wheels для быстрой установки зависимостей](https://dizballanze.com/ru/python-wheels-dlia-bystroi-ustanovki-zavisimostei/)