# Как установить модуль Python на компьютер без интернета

Tags: python, pip

Дано:компьютер без интернета,Windows 7, установлен Python 3.8, в Path добавлен.Pip установлен.На сайте PyPi скачал модуль pyperclip, два файла, архив и с расширением whl. Пытаюсь их поставить через командную строку, ничего не выходит.Вылезает куча ворнингов,что невозможно установить соединение, и в конце ошибка Could not Find a version.
Буду благодарен за советы.Просьба разжевывать объяснения как для идиота)))потому что только только начал изучать Python.

Comment: Нужно качать не только модуль, но и зависимости этого модуля. И про зависимости зависимостей модуля тоже не забыть

Comment: Тот вопрос немного про другое, но вот этот ответ как раз под вашу ситуацию: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1382136/1365

Comment: А что за зависимости,и где их взять?

Comment: И вообще лучше взять какую-нибудь `Anaconda` в максимальной комплектации, там много чего предустановлено заранее будет.