# Локальная установка библеотек Python(Requests, urllib3)

Tags: python, pip

Машина локальная, отлученная от интернет сети. Мне нужно спарсить наш локальный сайт и собрать информацию для отчета. Для реализации поставленной задачи я выбрал beautifulsoup. Для его работы вдруг потребовались библиотеки Request, для url запросов. Скачал поставил и столкнулся с проблемой.

```
C:\Users\ ......\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Scripts\python.exe
C:\Users\ ......\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"C:\Users\ ......\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 2, in
<module>
    import requests   File "C:\Users\ .......\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\requests-2.28.2-py3.11.egg\requests\__init__.py",
line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3'
```

Устанавливаю urllib3, ей тоже не хочется ставится локально!

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\ ......\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1py
.\download\urllib3-main\setup.py install     

 ===============================   
 Unsupported installation method
 ===============================

This version of urllib3 has dropped support for Python 2.7 and no
longer supports installation with `python setup.py install`.

Please use `python -m pip install .` instead.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Посоветуйте пожалуйста, как их установить и заставить работать через локальную установку!?

upd

попытка установки библиотеки urllib3 командой `py -m pip install .\download\urllib3-2.0.0a3\` , если это команда предназначена для локальной установки то почему она пытается выйти в интернет и выполнить действие с сертификатами, и что она пытается с ними сделать?

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\ryzhonkov.ia\PycharmProjects\pythonProject> py -m pip install .\download\urllib3-2.0.0a3\                               
Processing c:\users\ryzhonkov.ia\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\download\urllib3-2.0.0a3
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [10 lines of output]
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to ge
t local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)'))': /simple/hatchling/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to ge
t local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)'))': /simple/hatchling/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to ge
t local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)'))': /simple/hatchling/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to ge
t local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)'))': /simple/hatchling/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to ge
t local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)'))': /simple/hatchling/
      Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/hatchling/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/hatchling/ (Caused by SSLError(
SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)'))) - skipping
      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement hatchling<2,>=1.6.0 (from versions: none)
      ERROR: No matching distribution found for hatchling<2,>=1.6.0
      Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerif
icationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)'))) - skipping
      WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificatio
nError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)'))) - skipping
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
(venv) PS C:\Users\ryzhonkov.ia\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>
```

Установка .whl файла командой `py -m pip .\download\request-2.28.2-py3-none-any.whl` опять сертификаты!

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\ryzhonkov.ia\PycharmProjects> py -m pip .\download\request-2.28.2-py3-none-any.whl
Processing c:\users\ryzhonkov.ia\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\download\requests-2.28.2-py3-none-any.whl
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get loca
l issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)'))': /simple/charset-normalizer/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get loca
l issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)'))': /simple/charset-normalizer/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get loca
l issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)'))': /simple/charset-normalizer/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get loca
l issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)'))': /simple/charset-normalizer/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get loca
l issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)'))': /simple/charset-normalizer/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/charset-normalizer/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/charset-normalizer/ (Caused 
by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)'))) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement charset-normalizer<4,>=2 (from requests) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for charset-normalizer<4,>=2
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificatio
nError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)'))) - skipping
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
```

Comment: Если смотреть по тексту ошибки, то такое впечатление, что вы пытаетесь urllib3 установить на Python 2.7.

Comment: я пытаюсь установить локально. Я смог что то получить реакцию через команду py .\download\urllib3\setup.py install предварительно скачав её с гидхаба. Большинство манов с ютубчика очень красиво расказывают о том как устанавливать библиотеки с помощью pip через интернет с репозитория и все забывают что иногда приходится это делать локально, а это затрудненно.

Comment: Посмотрите вот этот ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1382136/1365

Comment: Кстати, во втором фрагменте вам явно пишет, что нужно устанавливать через `python -m pip install .` вместо `setup.py install`. Но через скачивание whl файла со всеми зависимостями все-же проще будет (см. мой комментарий выше).

Comment: Я пытался, но на машине с интернетом у меня линукс, не получилось. Могу конечно дома попробовать сделать шаблон папки venv\lib\ для работы. Заметил что во время установок установщик ругается с сертификатами и пытается подключится к https://pypi.org/simple/pip, пробую понять что творится в этом направлении проблемы. Интернета та нет, машина локальная.

Comment: Тогда ставьте такой же линукс на виртуалку, на ней скачивайте whl пакеты. "Могу конечно дома попробовать сделать шаблон папки venv\lib\ для работы." - это не сработает, для Windows и для Linux создаются кардинально разные виртуальные окружения.

Comment: То есть на машине с выходом в интернет мне нужна ОС идентичная на которой мне работать в питоне на локальной машине?

Comment: Да, желательно чтобы все максимально совпадало. Как минимум должна совпадать битность и версия Python.

Comment: У меня на машинке с выходом в интернет линукс, а на рабочей вин10. Логично что я скачиваю библиотеки на линуксе, а работаю на винде.

Comment: Вот чтобы вам на linux поставить модули, вам нужно их скачивать из-под linux. Поэтому нужна виртуалка.

Comment: "если это команда предназначена для локальной установки то почему она пытается выйти в интернет и выполнить действие с сертификатами, и что она пытается с ними сделать?" - видимо пытается скачать свои зависимости. Делайте через `pip wheel -w wheels/ requests` и не мучайтесь, так выкачает все зависимости рекурсивно.

Comment: "Установка .whl файла командой py -m pip .\download\request-2.28.2-py3-none-any.whl опять сертификаты!" - перейдите по ссылке во втором моем комментарии и посмотрите, как нужно устанавливать.

Comment: Так вы на windows устанавливаете или на linux?

Comment: на вин10, попробую дома с винды скачать и установить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблемы решил 2 действиями.

1. Скачал библиотеки с идентичной ОС. На моей рабочей машине Виндовс,
   качал с виндовс.
2. Для скачивания библиотек с зависимостями использовал команды wheel.

- `pip install wheels` - не обязательно, скачивает wheel, в актуальных
  версиях питона она встроена.
- `pip wheel -w wheels/ requests`/`pip wheel -w wheels/ [имя_библиотеки]` - скачивает библиотеку и зависимости c ней. создает папку wheels в папке с проектом.
- заходим в папку проекта, архивируем или проста копируем папку wheels, переносим на рабочий компьютер в папку с проектом для дальнейшей установки библиотек.
- Устанавливаем библиотеки на рабочем компьютере при помощи команды `pip install --no-index -f wheels/ requests`/`pip install --no-index -f wheels/ [имя_библиотеки]`

Получаем два вывода. Первое зависимость ОС и зависимость с зависимостями библиотек. Что препятствует простой установки библиотек для локальных работ.

Answer (score 1):

Если у Вас есть возможность залить какой-то файл на локальную машину, то Вы можете сделать следующие действия:

1. Зайти на сайт `pypi.org` и найти там модуль `urllib`
   (Вот Вам ссылка на этот модуль на pypi: https://pypi.org/project/urllib3/2.0.0a3/#files)
2. Перейдите в пункт **"Загрузка файлов"** и нажмите по гиперссылке с нужней версией с расширением  `.whl` (Вот Вам ссылка на этот файл: https://pypi.org/project/urllib3/2.0.0a3/#fileshttps://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a2/e6/439fae33e93f8aa172d339928f7a7766bd3a5c6c1e1ef2f786d73ca9b52c/urllib3-2.0.0a3-py3-none-any.whl)
3. После загрузки файла залейте его на свою **локальную машину**
4. Запустите `консоль/терминал` и **перейдите в директорию со скачанным файлом!**
5. Введите команду `python3 -m pip3 install "ИМЯ_ФАЙЛА_С_РАСШИРЕНИЕМ"`

После проделанных действий модуль должен успешно установиться на машину!

Comment: не получилось пишет. urllib3 is already installed with the same version as the provided wheel. Use --force-reinstall to force an installation of the wheel. Так же спрашивает Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificatio

Comment: Ошибка говорит о том что у Вас уже устанволен urllib. Для решение этой пробемы есть два варианта!
Первый: Вам нужно к Вашей итоговой комманде добавить флаг `--force-install`.
Второй: Пропишите сначала комманду `pip uninstall urllib3`, подтвердите действия удаления модуля и после повторите итоговую комманду.